# Change Angular Material table style

Tags: angular, angular-material

I use Data-Table from angular material and i want to change the table style.

[image]

How can i remove the border/frame from the table and remove the 3d effect on the frame?

Comment: Do you mean `mat-table`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the by default css that is adding box shadow just change the values and add !important and then you are good to go.

```
.mat-elevation-z8 {
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 8px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 3px 14px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe that you take an example from the [doc](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples), so just simply remove the elevation [helper](https://material.angular.io/guide/elevation)

```
class="mat-elevation-z8"
```

from `mat-table`.